# Dgrid + Selection Issue

Tags: dgrid

Still trying to work with Dgrid (0.4) and dojo (1.10), I have now another issue with the selection.

My web page contain a Dialog opened when you click on a button.
Inside this dialog, we have the following code which display a grid with data coming from a database through a Json HTTP page. This is working fine, even sorting and query filtering.

What I want to do know is to allow the user to double click on a row, get the selected row Id contains in the first column to update the form in the main page. I use the dgrid/selection for this. However, it always return the last row of the grid instead of the one the user selected.

The selection code is based on this :
  http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/hello_dgrid/

Any idea?

Thanks

```
      <script language="javascript">  

        require
        (
            [
                "dojo/_base/declare", 
                "dojo/_base/array", 
                "dgrid/OnDemandList",
                "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
                "dgrid/Keyboard",
                "dgrid/Selection",
                "dgrid/Editor", 
                "dgrid/extensions/ColumnHider",
                "dstore/Memory",
                "dstore/RequestMemory",
                "dojo/_base/lang",
                "dojo/dom-construct",
                "dojo/dom",
                "dojo/on",
                "dojo/when",
                "dojo/query",
                "dojo/store/Observable",
                "dstore/Rest",
                "dojo/_base/Deferred",
                "dojo/store/Cache",
                "dojo/domReady!",
            ], 
            function(
                declare, arrayUtil,  OnDemandList, OnDemandGrid, Keyboard, Selection, Editor, ColumnHider, Memory, RequestMemory, lang, ObjectStore, dom, on, when, query, Observable, Rest, Deferred
            ){
                var fform = dom.byId("filterForm");
                var ContactColumns = [
                        { label: "", field: "contact_id", hidden: true,  unhidable: true},
                        { label: "Company Name", field: "company_name", unhidable: true },
                        { label: "Contact Name", field: "contact_name", unhidable: true },
                        { label: "Email", field: "contact_email", unhidable: true }
                ];

                var ContactGrid=declare([OnDemandGrid, Keyboard, Selection,ColumnHider]);

                var contactlist = new Observable(new Rest({ target: './ajax.contactsLoader.php' }));
                var selection = [];

                window.contactgrid = new ContactGrid(
                    {
                        className: "dgrid-selectors",
                        collection: contactlist,
                        maxRowsPerPage:10,
                        selectionMode: 'single',
                        cellNavigation: false,
                        columns: ContactColumns
                    }, "contacttable"
                );

                on(fform, "submit", function (event) {
                        var cpy_filter = fform.elements.fcompany_name.value;
                        var ct_filter = fform.elements.fcontact_name.value;
                        var email_filter = fform.elements.fcontact_email.value;                                             
                    contactgrid.set('collection',contactlist.filter({contact_name: ct_filter, company_name: cpy_filter, contact_email: email_filter }));
                       contactgrid.refresh();
                        event.preventDefault();
                });

            contactgrid.on('dgrid-select', function (event) {
                // Report the item from the selected row to the console.
                console.log('Row selected: ', event.rows[0].data);
            });
            contactgrid.on('dgrid-deselect', function (event) {
                console.log('Row de-selected: ', event.rows[0].data);
            });
            contactgrid.on('.dgrid-row:click', function (event) {
                var row = contactgrid.row(event);
                console.log('Row clicked:', row.data);
            });


            }    
        );
       </script>             

 <div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea" style="width:96%;margin-left:5px">
    <form id="filterForm">        
      <div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar" >
    <button           data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" type="submit">Filter</button>          
        <button
          data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button"
          data-dojo-attach-point="submitButton"
          type="submit"
        >
          Select
        </button>

        <button
          data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button"
          data-dojo-attach-point="cancelButton"
        >
          Close
        </button>

      </div>


        <div data-dojo-attach-point="contentNode" >
        <input type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" name="fcompany_name" id="fcompany_name" style="width:33%">
        <input type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" name="fcontact_name" id="fcontact_name" style="width:32%">
        <input type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"  name="fcontact_email" id="fcontact_email" style="width:33%">

        <div id="contacttable">
        </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what's returned by your REST endpoint?  "it always return the last row of the grid instead of the one the user selected" sounds like it could be an issue with the items not having proper unique identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the reason.
the columns need to have a 'id' column called ID. I just change the 'contact_id' column to 'id' and it works fine.

thanks

Comment: It is not necessary to change the `field` to `id`. You can set `idProperty` on your collection also. Just give it the same name as the required `field`. Like `idProperty: contact_id`.